# Problema ao ler arquivo de propriedades

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Criei um arquivo de propertie para o banco ler esse arquivo a partir daí mas o console me apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Erronull\properties\conexao.propertie (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
Erronull\properties\conexao.propertie (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
Erronull\properties\conexao.propertie (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
ConexaoMySQL: The url cannot be null
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at modelo.ConexaoMySQL.conectar(ConexaoMySQL.java:18)
    at helper.BancoDadosHelper.getNomeColunas(BancoDadosHelper.java:18)
    at principal.Main.testaConexDB(Main.java:38)
    at principal.Main.menu(Main.java:30)
    at principal.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at helper.BancoDadosHelper.getNomeColunas(BancoDadosHelper.java:21)
    at principal.Main.testaConexDB(Main.java:38)
    at principal.Main.menu(Main.java:30)
    at principal.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

***Classe ConexaoMysql:***

```
package modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexaoMySQL {

    private static Connection conexao;

    public static boolean conectar() {
        Propriedade.setPath(System.getProperty("jdbc.url")+"\\properties\\conexao.propertie");
        String url = Propriedade.getValor("url");
        String usr = Propriedade.getValor("user");
        String pwd = Propriedade.getValor("password");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pwd);
            System.out.println("ConexaoMySQL.conectar");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ConexaoMySQL: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void fecharConexao() {
        if (conexao != null) {
            try {
                conexao.close();
                conexao = null;
                System.out.println("ConexaoMySQL.fecharConexao");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("ConexaoMySQL: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConexao(){
        return conexao;
    }

}
```

***Classe Propriedade :***

```
package modelo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Propriedade {

    private static String path;

    public static void setPath(String caminhoDoArquivo) {
        path = caminhoDoArquivo;
    }

    public static String getValor(String key) {
        String returning = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            prop.load(fis);
            returning = prop.getProperty(key);
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return returning;
    }

}
```

**Arquivo conexao.propertie:**

```
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistema;
user = root;
password = ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto seu arquivo de propriedades, quanto o código que o recupera, estão errados, sendo a raiz do erro devido ao fato de o arquivo não ser encontrado.

O erro apresentado é:

> O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado

Veja que você está recuperando (`System.getProperty("jdbc.url")`) uma propriedade de sistema que é neste momento inexistente, para forma o *path* e está retornando `null` sendo o caminho final gerado igual a `null\properties\conexao.propertie`

Para isto, considere recuperar o arquivo de propriedades como um *resource stream*, caso ele este no *classpath* de sua aplicação, algo desta forma:

```
InputStream fis = Propriedade.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties/conexao.propertie")
```

Isto faz com que seja desnecessário o `setPath` da classe `Propriedade`. Uma outra observação é que você pode carregar o arquivo de propriedades uma única vez, num bloco estático mesmo.

Então, no final, a classe `Propriedade` se pareceria com isto:

```
public final class Propriedade {

    private Propriedade() {}

    private static final Properties prop = new Properties();

    static {
        try (final InputStream fis = Propriedade.class.getResourceAsStream("/properties/conexao.propertie")) {
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String getValor(final String key) {
        final String returning = prop.getProperty(key);
        return returning != null ? returning : key;
    }

}
```

Por último, considerando o conteúdo do seu arquivo de propriedades:

```
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistema;
user = root;
password = ;
```

Isto irá retornar sempre o `;` o que, no caso de usuário e senha, provavelmente irá gerar erro.

Se possível for, prefira este conteúdo:

```
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistema
user = root
password =
```

Para utilizar é da mesma forma que você estava fazendo antes, `Propriedade.getValor("propriedade")`, mas em `conectar` de `ConexaoMySQL` você deverá remover a primeira linha do método.

Um exemplo recuperando é este:

```
System.out.println("Propriedade 'user' (valor=root;): " + Propriedade.getValor("user"));
System.out.println("Propriedade 'key' (inexistente): " + Propriedade.getValor("key"));
```

Que gera este resultado:

```
Propriedade 'user' (valor=root;): root;
Propriedade 'key' (inexistente): key
```

Comment: No método conectar eu retiro este trecho então ?(Propriedade.setPath(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\properties\\conexao.propertie"); ), mas mesmo assim está dando erro.

Comment: @Jarwin isto, retira ele e usa a classe desta forma. O arquivo está no classpath da sua aplicação, não está? Outra coisa: removeu os `;` das propriedades?

Comment: Cara fica meio difícil explicar o erro que está acontecendo, aqui está o meu código completo para você entender melhor a minha situação: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vo699f7b4nz1v9/AulaBanco.zip?dl=0 e o meu arquivo sql:  http://pastebin.com/LxfWA3GG

Comment: @Jarwin cara, posta o erro, infelizmente não posso pegar seu projeto e testar aqui, simplesmente não vou instalar o MySQL para isso ou converter o SQL para executar em outro banco. Esta resposta resolve o seu erro inicial, se é outro erro completamente diferente, considere criar outra resposta.

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at modelo.ConexaoMySQL.conectar(ConexaoMySQL.java:13)
 at helper.BancoDadosHelper.getNomeColunas(BancoDadosHelper.java:18)
 at principal.Main.testaConexDB(Main.java:38)
 at principal.Main.menu(Main.java:30)
 at principal.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
 at modelo.Propriedade.<clinit>(Propriedade.java:15)
 ... 5 more'

Comment: @Jarwin seu arquivo de propriedades não está no *classpath* da aplicação, assim como não está em uma pasta chamada *properties* que esteja no *classpath*. Coloque o arquivo `conexao.propertie` na pasta `src` e altere de `/properties/conexao.propertie` para `/conexao.propertie`

Comment: Agora deu esse erro:  ConexaoMySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659) .............    E eu não tenho senha no meu banco...

Comment: @Jarwin cara, tu tá lendo as mensagens de erro? Conseguiu ver que o problema é de autenticação? Dê uma olhada, faça as alterações necessárias, a melhor forma de aprender é explorar os problemas e não apenas esperar que alguém faça o seu trabalho de casa cara, se você olhar o métod o `getValor` de `Propriedade` verá o por que do erro, é simples, de toda forma a resposta está atualizada...

Comment: Deu certo cara, desculpa ficar insistindo em erros toda hora é que eu até não conseguir descobrir o que está acontecendo eu fico doido !!!! só queria entender porque da retirada do returning.length() > 0  ?

Comment: @Jarwin este *por que* deixarei para você descobrir, fazer testes e tudo o mais, verá o por que ele fez diferença no seu caso :)

Comment: Ok ^^, Você me recomenda algum bom livro para aprender java web e JDBC, tendo em vista sua experiência ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24593/discussion-between-jarwin-and-bruno-cesar).